# Angular JS can I load a service just on the js I need it and not in the app.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, service, module

I tried doing something like:

```
var vehicle_info = angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', vehicle_info]);
var name = vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass($rootScope.data.user.vehicles[i].vclass.id);
```

But I get this:

```
vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass is not a function
at dashboard.js?v=@@TIMESTAMP:288
at angular.js:9369
at angular.js:13189
at l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
at l.$digest (angular.js:14217)
at l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
at l (angular.js:9659)
at S (angular.js:9849)
at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (angular.js:9790)
```

Why?

Before I would do it like this, in the app.js file:

```
 angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', vehicle_info]);
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'route-segment', 'view-segment', 'ngCookies', 'ngImgCrop', 'ngSanitize', 'psngr.payment', 'psngr.storage', 'psngr.unit', 'psngr.vehicle_info']);
```

Where:

```
 app = app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout, $http, $window, storage, unit) {
    $rootScope.unit = unit;
}
```

But I won't want it to have a rootScope, and be global, I only want to load the script file in the html that I use it. so I would like to load the module just in the js file of that html. Is it possible?

EDIT:

The vehicle_info.js file that contains the service looks like this:

```
 var vehicle_info = function($rootScope, $timeout, $q) {
function getNameOfVclass(vclass) {
    switch(vclass) {
        case 1:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize');
        case 2:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.large');
        case 3:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.compact');
        case 4:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.scooter');
        case 5:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.motorcycle');
        case 6:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.suv');
        case 7:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.van');
        case 8:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.pickup');
        case 9:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.truck');
        case 10:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.bicycle');
        default:
            return i18n.t('psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize');
    }
}

//Exposed methods
return {
    /*  get name of vclass */
    getNameOfVclass: function(vclass) {
        return getNameOfVclass(vclass);
    },
};
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can but you can't use a service before initialising it.

```
var vehicle_info = angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', vehicle_info]);
var name = vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass($rootScope.data.user.vehicles[i].vclass.id);
```

instead do something like this.
First define your service

```
var vehicle_info = angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q']);
```

Now include it in controller.
Read [Factory Recipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) Here

Comment: Thanks, will look into this, this answer is pretty straight forward, I will read on the factory recipe and let you know if I will manage.
Sorry to see that some asshole downvoted this answer, even tho' it seems pretty accurate

Comment: Sure. Hope it will help. 
Happens sometime :p

Comment: I tried with `var vehicle_info = angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q']);` But I still get the same issue: vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass is not a function

Comment: If you can share lil more source code where you have this 'getNameOfVClass' function, that would help to understand exact problem.

Comment: You don't have necessarily to use $rootScope, use $scope for local scope. And your service has to be an angular service registered with main App or through other module. I think that would do your task.

Comment: You can follow the procedure as given in docs https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134553/discussion-between-psycho-and-rosu-alin).

Comment: Did manage to fix it, using Alex Netrebsky answer from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978661/angular-js-how-to-move-the-service-in-a-separate-js-file/41978729?noredirect=1#comment71135339_41978729

Answer (score 0):

**Why you get the error:** `vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass is not a function`

The very first line isn't doing what you think it's doing. It looks as though you are trying to assign an instance of the `vehicle_info` factory to a variable called `vehicle_info`:

```
var vehicle_info = angular.module('psngr.vehicle_info', []).factory('vehicle_info', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q', vehicle_info]);
```

What is actually happening here is you are assigning the `psngr.vehicle_info` module to the `vehicle_info` variable. This is because the call to the module's `.factory()` function doesn't return an instance of the factory, it returns the module which enables chaining. So after declaring the first variable, the error becomes apparent on the second line:

```
var name = vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass($rootScope.data.user.vehicles[i].vclass.id);
```

Here, you are looking for a function called `getNameOfVclass` on the module, and of course it's not there, or as Angular puts it: **getNameOfVclass is not a function**.

**To use an instance of a factory**

You have to inject it into another angular component (usually a controller) in which you wish to use it. So in your case, your code could become something like this (and I have changed names as I would prefer to name them):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('appController', function($scope, vehicleInfoService) {
    $scope.name = vehicleInfoService.getNameOfVclass();
});

app.factory('vehicleInfoService', function ($rootScope, $timeout, $q){
    return {
        getNameOfVclass: function(){
            return "ABC";
        }
    }
});
```

Then as a basic example, in index.html you could have something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="appController">
    <p>The name of the v class is: {{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

**[Example Plunk Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mgJfIbci8ep34kc5uAVI?p=preview)**

Comment: And how can I get an instance of the service, so I can call getNameOfVclass? I'm new to angular, and I'm trying to understand how to call it. The only example I have to follow, si the one that I posted, from inside app.js, but I need to do it locally in my dashboard.js file, hence the issue

Comment: I've updated my answer. It sounds like you are trying to break your project down into the small components and you are thinking very carefully where things belong - which is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: In my example I have lumped it all together in one file but this is not a good practice. I would normally have an `app.js` to define the module, an `appController.js` to define the controller and a `vehicleInfoService.js` to define the service. In your example it sounds like dashboard.js would be where you define a `dashboardController` and that's where you need to inject your service (in much the same way that I did in `appController`).

Comment: ok, thanks, will take a look at this. Well, yes, my boss doesn't want me to make all this services in the app.js (global) cause having them inside the memory is not quite good practice, they want me to open is just when I'm in the js file that uses it

Comment: What I  don't understand, is in my App.js file, I have to init the app variable as this:

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'route-segment', 'view-segment', 'ngCookies', 'ngImgCrop', 'ngSanitize', 'psngr.payment', 'psngr.storage', 'psngr.unit', 'psngr.vehicle_info']);`

Do I need to do the same thing in my dashboard.js?
Or will this be easier? Like `app = angular.module('app', 'psngr.vehicle_info')` ?

Comment: Ah I see your problem. Your question is really "do I have to declare all my module dependencies every time I want to add a controller/service/factory to my module?".. no you don't. When you use `angular.module('app', [])` you are creating a new module, when you use `angular.module('app')` you are retrieving the existing module and this is what you need to do as I have done in **[this new plunk here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7BZzJawrbnk2LY2OWwg?p=preview)**

Comment: Has this answered your question?

Comment: not yet, working on it. I  started a separate project, to try to understand how angular works, when I will get to this, I will let you know