# Angular.js how to move the service in a separate .js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, factory

Using the examples from their documentation I did this .html file:

```
  <html>

  <head>
  <title>Angular JS Services</title>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

  <div ng-app = "mainApp" ng-controller = "VehicleInfo">
     <p>Enter a number: <input type = "number" ng-model = "number" /></p>
     <button ng-click = "getNameOfVclass()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
     <p>Result: {{result}}</p>
  </div>
```

Now I have a test.js file, that looks like this:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

     mainApp.factory('VehicleInfo', function() {
        var factory = {};
        return factory;
     });

     mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', function(VehicleInfo){
        this.getNameOfVclass = function(a) {
           switch(a) {
              case 1:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
              case 2:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.large';
              case 3:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.compact';
              case 4:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.scooter';
              case 5:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.motorcycle';
              case 6:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.suv';
              case 7:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.van';
              case 8:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.pickup';
              case 9:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.truck';
              case 10:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.bicycle';
              default:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
           }
        }
     });

     mainApp.controller('VehicleInfo', function($scope, VehicleInfoService) {
        $scope.getNameOfVclass = function() {
           $scope.result = VehicleInfoService.getNameOfVclass($scope.number);
        }
     });
```

Now if I press the button, it will return 1 of those strings. Which is good.
What I want to do, is move the mainApp.service(....) inside a /services/vehicle_info.js file. Is that possible?

So that I  can then call the service like:

```
 mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', methodFromVehicleInfo.js);
```

I am a Android developer, that started working with AngularJS only yesterday, so I'm sorry if this question is too simple, or some might consider this common knowledge, but I'm just trying to figure out how angularJS works with javascript

EDIT:
What I tried is:
I made the services/vehicle_info.js like this:

```
var vehicle_info = function($rootScope, $timeout, $q) {
 function getNameOfVclass(vclass) {
  switch(vclass) {
  case 1:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
  case 2:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.large';
  case 3:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.compact';
  case 4:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.scooter';
  case 5:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.motorcycle';
  case 6:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.suv';
  case 7:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.van';
  case 8:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.pickup';
  case 9:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.truck';
  case 10:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.bicycle';
  default:
     return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
  }
   }

  //Exposed methods
  return {
  /* get name of vclass */
  getNameOfVclass: function(vclass) {
     return getNameOfVclass(vclass);
  },
  };
};
 mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', vehicle_info);
```

And from my test.js file, I tried this:

var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

```
     mainApp.factory('VehicleInfo', function() {
        var factory = {};
        return factory;
     });

     mainApp.controller('VehicleInfo', function($scope, VehicleInfoService) {
        $scope.getNameOfVclass = function() {
           $scope.result = VehicleInfoService.getNameOfVclass($scope.number);
        }
     });
```

This works!!! Which is great :D Thanks to Alex Netrebsky.
My next question is how to call this method from a .js file, and not via the ng-click from the button?

Comment: if you are starting to learn AngularJS, I advice you to take a look at Webpack. It will help you to struture better the angular. Do it now and will save you a lot later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just as folowing:

1. Move definition of service from `mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', function(VehicleInfo){` to the vehicle_info.js
2. Add `<script src="services/vehicle_info.js"></script>` into the `<HEAD>`tag
3. In the vehicle_info.js to get the module use `var myApp = angular.module("mainApp");`

Comment: I did some edits, can you check that pls? I need to move all the mainApp.service inside the vehicleInfo? not just the function for the service?

Comment: So, I added mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', vehicle_info); In the vehicle_info.js file, and now it works. Thanks a lot :D
Another question I would have, is how to call the function from a .js file? instead of pressing the button?

Comment: To call the function that is defined in another file you should make it public, the most direct way to define public function:

`window.myFunction1 = function() { ... } `

Which function to you want to call?

Comment: So basically I want from a js file to do something similar to this:
`vehicle_info.getNameOfVclass($rootScope.data.user.vehicles[i].vclass.id)`

PS This is being done from the test.js file, where I create the mainApp var

Comment: As I understand, you want to invoke method of the service outside of angular controller. If it's correct. Look at next 2 steps:

1. Replace the `var vehicle_info = function($rootScope, $timeout, $q) {` on `window.vehicle_info = function() {`

2. In other js file you can do the next:
`var vehicle = new vehicle_info().getNameOfVclass(1);`

Answer (score 2):

There are several code structures to achieve this, but one way or another you must retrieve (and then append the service to) the module in the new file:

**vehicle_info.js  (Using Chaining)**

```
angular.module("mainApp").service('VehicleInfoService', function(VehicleInfo){
        this.getNameOfVclass = function(a) {
           switch(a) {
              case 1:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
              case 2:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.large';
              case 3:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.compact';
              case 4:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.scooter';
              case 5:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.motorcycle';
              case 6:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.suv';
              case 7:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.van';
              case 8:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.pickup';
              case 9:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.truck';
              case 10:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.bicycle';
              default:
                 return 'psngr.profile.vehicle.car.midsize';
           }
        }
     });
```

**vehicle_info.js  (Using Separate Statements)**

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp");

mainApp.service('VehicleInfoService', function(VehicleInfo){
    this.getNameOfVclass = function(a) {
       // Your Switch Statement here...
    };
});
```

**vehicle_info.js  (Using Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**

```
(function(app)
    var vehicleInfoService = function(VehicleInfo) {        
       this.getNameOfVclass = function(a) {
           // Your switch statement here...
       };
    };

    app.service("VehicleInfoService", vehicleInfoService);
)(angular.module("mainApp"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is syntax. DO accordingly to your requirement.

Create a service folder.
In that create a any service file. letsay, vehicleService.js.

In that create service like this

```
app.service('vechileservice', function(){

this.add = function(a, b){
    return a + b;
};

this.subtract = function(a, b){
    return a - b;
};

this.multiply = function(a, b){
    return a * b;
};

this.divide = function(a, b){
    return a / b;
};

});
```

Above vechileservice is name of service, call it in controller wherever you want.
Dont forget to include file source in your index.html page.